# How to import tensorflow lite in libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx, build.gradle, tensorflow-lite

I want to use tensorflow lite in libgdx. I'm just using the android subclass, but in my Game.java, I cannot import tensorflow lite. If I try to import it, using import org.tensorflow.lite., I can only see the branch `.schema and .support.` [image]

But I need import org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter for importing my trained .tflite file.
I don't know why it isn't working, so can please somebody help, who knows what I'm doing wrong?

> **build.gradle(PDetection)**

```
buildscript {


    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'


    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "PDetection"
        gdxVersion = '1.10.0'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.12'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.5'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.3'
        aiVersion = '1.8.2'
        gdxControllersVersion = '2.1.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "com.android.application"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"

    dependencies {
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.1.0-rc1'
        implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-metadata:0.1.0-rc1'
        implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-task-vision:0.1.0'
        implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-task-text:0.1.0'
        implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+'
    }
}
```

> **build.gradle(:android)**

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    compileSdkVersion 29
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/robovm/ios/robovm.xml'
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "tflite"
        noCompress "lite"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "iolgithub.toberocat"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives {
    doFirst {
        file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs()
        file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs()
        file("libs/arm64-v8a/").mkdirs()
        file("libs/x86_64/").mkdirs()
        file("libs/x86/").mkdirs()

        configurations.natives.copy().files.each { jar ->
            def outputDir = null
            if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-arm64-v8a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/arm64-v8a")
            if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
            if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
            if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86_64.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86_64")
            if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
            if(outputDir != null) {
                copy {
                    from zipTree(jar)
                    into outputDir
                    include "*.so"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { packageTask ->
    if (packageTask.name.contains("package")) {
        packageTask.dependsOn 'copyAndroidNatives'
    }
}

task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'iolgithub.toberocat/iolgithub.toberocat.AndroidLauncher'
}

eclipse.project.name = appName + "-android"
```